# Prove $f:D\to D.$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D$ be the unit disk, and let $C$ be the unit circle.
Suppose that $f$ is analytic on a domain containing $\overline D$. I'm trying to prove that if  $f:C\to C$ and there exists $z_0\in D$ such that $f(z_0)\in D$, 
then $f:D\to D$. Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the maximum modulus principle, $f$ attains its maximum modulus on the boundary.

Then, given that $f: C \to C$, we must have that $f: D \to D$, as required.

Comment: But $C\cup \{z_0\}$ is not a connected set, right?

Comment: The domain in consideration is $D$, which *is* connected.  @Kelan

Comment: There are surely continuous maps that map the circle to itself, map a point in the interior of the unit ball to the interior of the unit ball, but do not map $D$ to $D$.

Comment: Hi @PeterFranek, do you have an example of a mapping?

Comment: How about $2\cos^2 (\pi|z|)/(1+|x|)?$

Comment: Yes, for example, in polar coordinates, $r,\phi \mapsto g(r), \phi$ where $g$ is any continuous function mapping $0$ to $0$, $1$ to $1$ and $1/2$ to $1/2$ and $1/4$ to $1000$.

Comment: Ok, so how should I modify my answer? @zhw My next guess at an answer would be to actually use the analyticity of $F$ -- the open mapping theorem comes to mind.

Comment: Just use the maximum modulus theorem.

Comment: Ah, of course.  A one-line proof.  Thanks so much, @zhw.

Comment: Thanks @PeterFranek -- I will correct my answer :)